# .Net Core UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\api\wwwroot' is denied

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core

We have a .net MVC application and a .Net Core Api Application.
The MVC application is deployed on Azure.
Core Api application is deployed on the api folder of the MVC application.
This is the structure.

Below code block gives permission error.

```
FileStream streamPolicy = new FileStream(policyStmnt, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

policyStmnt is => wwwroot/api/wwwroot/Content/amazonS3/CannedPolicy.txt

The file is in wwwroot/content/amazonS3 folder in the api application.
When reading this file on azure it gives error but on local it works as expected.

Is it something related to Azure?
How can I give permission or what is the reason for this.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Where is the line of code "FileStream streamPolicy = new FileStream(policyStmnt, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);"? in the MVC project or api project or some where?

Comment: May I know where you hosted your app ? Azure app service or something else ?

Comment: The error is "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot' is denied." @MohitVerma

Comment: The line of code is in a library where referenced by core api project. @IvanYang

Comment: The app is hosted on Azure as App Service. And the core api is deployed in Api folder of application. @StanleyGong

Comment: @KubilayBayraktar, I tried set up a similar project as you mentioned, and for policyStmnt, I used:  Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + @"\wwwroot\Content\amazonS3\CannedPolicy.txt"; It can read files. You can take a try it.

Comment: @IvanYang It says "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\api' is denied." now

Comment: @KubilayBayraktar, do you mind providing a sample of the web api and the library? so I can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @IvanYang let me prepare

Comment: @IvanYang login here with email and password 'tester' https://rementis.co/Account/SignIn. At the bottom right there is a floating menu, try to Add File from there. Check console and you will see error returns from api. You can check errors from this endpoint: https://tester.rementis.co/api/errors

Comment: problem fixed , thanks

Comment: @KubilayBayraktar, can you share the solution?

Comment: it is quite funny tough. It was because the reading settings is failed so that full path couldnt be created. This is why it was trying to read wwwroot instead of cannedpolicy.txt. Sorry for inconvenience..

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so it helps others in the community who have similar asks.